# Converting assembly code into machine code. What goes in this PC counter?

Tags: assembly, mips

I have this assignment:

[image]

In the example, what are the `0/32, 22, 16, 12` numbers on the third row?

[image]

In the above, why is the PC=4? I thought it should equal the current location of the instruction = LC?

I read somewhere that for the BNE instruction, the PC counter is treated differently, so it's a word address. So what would go in the PC column for the BNE instruction? I know that 4 bytes = 1 word so if the BNE was at PC=28 bytes, then it would 7 words? However, it needs to go back to the `next` label which is at 8 bytes=2 words... so what goes in the column? Do I enter -5 to imply that the next instruction is at the 2nd word?

**EDIT**

I have this filled out, but I'm still stuck:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they're using the PC column to indicate the ***next PC*** value ***after*** the instruction executes.

For most instructions (e.g. arithmetic & logical), next-PC is LC+4 — this is how sequential execution works.

However, for conditional branch instructions it is either next-PC (LC+4), or, the branch target address (PC+4+immediate*4).

For (unconditional) jump instructions, the next-PC is either an address computed by label (`j label` or `jal label`) or value in register (`jr $ra`).

For a BNE instruction, since it is a *conditional* branch, then in the abstract the next-PC could be one of two different values, and so, we need to know the state — the values in the registers — before we can choose one of the two possible next-PC values, because we need to know whether the conditional branch is taken or not taken.  If taken the next-PC is `PC+4+immediate*4`, and if not taken it is just `PC+4`.  It is taken if the condition specified is true (i.e. the two registers are vs. aren't equal in bit pattern).

---

0 / 32, 22, 17, 12 are:

opcode=***0***  ... 0 means R-Type instruction.   The opcode field is in bits 31-26.  So, when those bits are all 0, then we have an R-Type instructions.  An R-Type instruction has 3 register fields (bits 25-21, 20-16, 15-11), a SHAMT field (bits 10-6) and a FUNC field (bits 5-0).

All R-Type instructions have the same opcode 0, and they are differentiated by the FUNC field.  The FUNC value for an ADD instruction is ***32*** (which in binary is 100000 — can you identify this value in the binary expansion for the `ADD` instruction?).

The ***22***, ***17*** and ***12*** are register numbers, and they correspond to friendly assembler names of `$s6`, `$s1`, and `$t4`, respectively.

Comment: since it's a `next` label, we don't have to put the Location Counter of `next` in teh PC column?

Comment: The label has a value of LC at that position, so the label `next` has the value/address 4.  However, the PC value after the `LW` is (LC=4)+4=8, just like it is (LC=0)+4=4 after the `ADDI`, if you get what I mean.

Comment: And sorry for the confusion, in my answer, when I say "next PC" I am not in any way referring to the label named `next`.  When I say "next PC" I mean next in the sense of succeeding or following.

Comment: There are two examples of them using the PC column to mean ***the PC value after the instruction executes***: the `ADD` instruction in your first screenshot (where LC=32 and PC=36), and the `ADDI` in your second (where LC=0 and PC=4).  Thus, my conclusion that PC=LC+4 is the proper answer for non-branching instructions.  (Also recall that all MIPS instructions are each 4 bytes long.)

Comment: Sorry what does immediate mean? IF the label that I"m jumping back to has a Location Counter of 4 (which next does), then I get PC = PC + 4 + immediate = 24 + 4 + 4*6 = 52? That seems way off.

Comment: So what about for branching instructions. I added my work and I'm stuck as to what `next` and wht the `PC` should be on the BNe instruction. My greensheet says PC for BNE = PC + 4 + BranchAddr which I gather is 24 + 4 + 4... but that doesn't seem right?

Comment: The BNE instruction itself has address 24.  So, the PC value that the BNE will compute from is 24+4 (aka 28), which is one of the possible values for the PC column: the value in case it doesn't branch (conditional branch not taken). Now, when the BNE is taken (conditional branch taken), then it goes to location `next:` at address 4, and 4, then is the second possible value for the PC column.  If we don't know whether the branch is taken or not, then there are necessarily two answers for the PC column: 28 and 4.

Comment: If you are instructed to assume taken then choose 4, whereas if you are instructed to assume not taken, then choose 28, and if you are not instructed one way or another, then write 4/28 or "4 or 28" something like that to indicate the two answers for the PC column for this instruction.

Comment: Btw, good job computing -6 for the immediate offset in the BNE.  It need to go to location 4 and is computing from 28, so you correctly computed (4-28)/4 = -24/4 = -6.

Comment: Your greensheet would be better to say BNE = PC + 4 + (immediate*4) rather than BranchAddr -- I would call that a typo on the greensheet.  We could also say that BNE = PC+4 ***or*** BranchAddr -- but I don't actually know what they mean by BranchAddr except maybe the branch target address (which in this case is 4), so ***if*** they define BranchAddr as immediate*4 (it would be weird and misleading if that were the case, to be sure), then it is not a typo otherwise it is a typo.  During execution the branch target address is computed as 28+(-6)*4 = 4.